# Re-arrange array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to rearrange an array in a specific way.

My input array structure is like this (edited):

```
  [
    [[elem1-1,elem1-2,elem1-3],int1],
    [[elem2-1,elem2-2,elem2-3],int2]
  ]
```

Explained: "elem[n-n]" means an element and "int[n]" is an integer.

Using structure above makes me write a very complicated loop in 2 levels to get my data and I need to rearrange the same array to look like this and avoid a second loop:

```
  [
    [elem1-1,int1],
    [elem1-2,int1],
    [elem1-3,int1],
    [elem2-1,int2],
    ...
  ]
```

The main difference between the arrays is the second one has all elements in row and repeats the int value for the input inline elements.

The point is I want to rearrange this array without use of any foreach instruction (which would result in the same 2 level loop), just doing by using map, reduce and so on.

I tried array map, but is still not working. See code below:

```
      //arr_in is the first array structure and arr_out is my expected output
      var arr_out = arr_in.map( function (elem){
        if (elem[0].size()>1) {
          return [//here is the problem, i guess]
        }
        else {
          return [elem[0], elem[1]]
        }
      });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: example of input and output? your mapping scheme is not obvious...

Comment: Your input array is unclear.  I get that you have an array, inside of which are sub-arrays of elements, but how does `[int1]` fit?  It isn't preceded by a comma.  Please add a practical example of your *actual* input data?

Comment: You can't without a forEach. Map will always return an array with the same lenght, reduce will ´reduce´ the array into a single value. You need a forEach (or any other way to iteract over the array, such as ´for´) because you have to create another array with other length.

Comment: @ingvar Check again, i made changes in the structure of input and output array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing, based on the code provided, that `arr_in` is a 2D array containing arrays in this form: `[elem1-1, elem1-2, ..., int1]`. If that so, then a `forEach`on the array and on its subs will do:

```
var arr_out = [];
arr_in.forEach( function (sub) {
  // sub = sub.slice(0);                    // uncomment this line if you don't want to alter the original array arr_in
  var int = sub.pop();                      // get the last item of this sub array, which is the "int"
  sub.forEach(function(elem) {              // for each other element left in the sub array
    arr_out.push([elem, int]);              // push a pair to the result array consisting of the current element and the "int"
  });
});
```

Which is shorter using an arrow function:

```
let arr_out = [];
arr_in.forEach( sub => {
  let int = sub.pop();
  sub.forEach(elem => arr_out.push([elem, int]));
});
```

And if you want a more functional way, you can always use a `reduce`:

```
let arr_out = arr_in.reduce((acc, sub) => {
  let int = sub.pop();
  sub.forEach(elem => acc.push([elem, int]));
  return acc;
}, []);
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr_in = [
  ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3", 7],
  ["elem1", 5],
  ["elem1", "elem2", 9]
];

let arr_out = [];
arr_in.forEach( sub => {
  let int = sub.pop();
  sub.forEach(elem => arr_out.push([elem, int]));
});

console.log(arr_out);
```

Comment: Great solution. I was trying to do it by not using a loop instruction, but your code works like a charm.

Comment: @danielarend You're welcome! If you want, I can post a simple `for` loop solution.

Answer (score -1):

You coud reduce the array by mappring the inner array or returning just the last result if the index is odd.

```js
var array = [[['elem1-1','elem1-2','elem1-3'], 'int1'], [['elem2-1','elem2-2','elem2-3'], 'int2']],
    result = array.reduce(
        (r, [a, b]) => r.concat(a.map(v => [v, b])),
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The array you have provided does not have the shape from the author's thread.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler, if op wants to get every item wrapped in an array, then this should work, now.

Comment: @NinaScholz, almost that. I just needed the 'int' value in the same row